# Jquery Declarative way with HTML5 data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html

Would you know a way to use Jquery in a declarative way?

Some of you will tell me to use AngularJS but isn't there something more lightweight, with only view side (no need routing and complex features because I'm using Symfony)

Is there a framework or library that would **replace** (I know it's bad practice but it's for the example):

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

**by**:

```
<any data-xx-event="click" data-xx-action="..."> </any>
```

Comment: Hi, check knockoutjs

Comment: Hello, yes this one was on my shortlist from TodoMVC but I wasn't sure it was the easiest/simplest thing since it offers large features :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the most popular github js repositories (> 300 stars) I found that the following lib/frameworks could meet the following constraints:

- Use data-* to bind js
- Play wells with Jquery
- Has strong community support
- Ideally can be used in unobtrusive ways but I am not 100% sure about this.

The list is:

- **Knockout** (http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-syntax.html) - 5 457* stars on Github
- **Backbone + Epoxy.js** (http://epoxyjs.org/index.html) - 477* stars on Github
- **Rivets.js** (http://rivetsjs.com/) - 1 820* stars on Github
- **intercooler.js** (http://intercoolerjs.org/) - 372* stars on Github

*As of 21/09/2014.

From what I've seen Knockout is very well documented and is a good start for beginning with JS framework/libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to [register new HTML elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) ?

Extracted from the page :

GOAL :

```
<hangout-module>
  <hangout-chat from="Paul, Addy">
    <hangout-discussion>
      <hangout-message from="Paul" profile="profile.png"
          profile="118075919496626375791" datetime="2013-07-17T12:02">
        <p>Feelin' this Web Components thing.</p>
        <p>Heard of it?</p>
      </hangout-message>
    </hangout-discussion>
  </hangout-chat>
  <hangout-chat>...</hangout-chat>
</hangout-module>
```

Some example the author of the page gives:

```
var XFooProto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype);

// 1. Give x-foo a foo() method.
XFooProto.foo = function() {
  alert('foo() called');
};

// 2. Define a property read-only "bar".
Object.defineProperty(XFooProto, "bar", {value: 5});

// 3. Register x-foo's definition.
var XFoo = document.registerElement('x-foo', {prototype: XFooProto});

// 4. Instantiate an x-foo.
var xfoo = document.createElement('x-foo');

// 5. Add it to the page.
document.body.appendChild(xfoo);
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer but I was more looking for something like knockoutjs

Comment: Is Xavier13's answer what you wanted ?